# Reescrita de URL no .htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess, url-amigável, mod-rewrite

tenho a seguinte URL:

```
http://<site>/application/views/ambiente_teste/assets-teste/...
```

E queria reecreve-la para:

```
http://<site>/assets-teste/...
```

Já tentei no meu .htaccess o seguinte:

```
RewriteRule ^assets-teste/?$ /application/views/ambiente_teste/assets-teste [NC,L]
```

Mas não sou muito experiente nisso, então gostaria de saber se ninguém tem uma solução.

Valeu ^^

Comment: `ReweiteRule` deveria ser `RewriteRule`. Será disso?

Comment: Sua URL não começa com **assets-teste**, então tira esse circunflexo que a expressão passa a casar apenas de trás pra frente e, salvo engano, vai funcionar.

Comment: @Zuul, isso foi erro de digitação aqui hehe.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, resolveu meu problema ^^
Muito obrigado aos dois, sou usuário novo, pois não encontrei a resposta que precisava, se quiserem me ensinar a dar uns pontinhos a vcs em agradecimento eu aceito. Valeu :)

Comment: @LuizFilipeMachadoBarni Aceitaste uma resposta mas a mesma não vai de encontro com a solução que o Bruno salientou e dizes ter resolvido o teu problema :/

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Coloca uma resposta com a tua solução dado ter resolvido o problema.

Comment: @zuul tem razão, eu editei a resposta pra fazer sentido, mas seria legal ter a do Bruno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa vai ser uma resposta expressa ^_^

Sua URL não começa com **assets-teste**, então tira esse circunflexo que a expressão passa a casar apenas de trás pra frente e então vai funcionar:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule assets-teste/?$ /application/views/ambiente_teste/assets-teste/ [NC,L]
```

Comment: resolveu meu problema, mas se eu prosseguir à um diretório subsequente, ex:`/assets-teste/css/` tenho uma página de 404. Então no final ainda estou com problemas :(

Comment: Aí já é um outro problema. Mas experimente trocar a interrogação da ER por **(\w+)** e lá na URL real, antes das flags, colocar **$1**, que representa o conteúdo capturado pelo grupo (parênteses).

Answer (score 0):

```
# Ativamos a reescrita
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Alterar URL
RewriteRule ^assets-teste /application/views/ambiente_teste/assets-teste/ [NC,QSA,L]
```